# jQuery - Mouseleave not firing

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, mouseleave

I am trying to inject some jQuery magic into a horizontal drop-down menu. On `mouseover/mouseenter` it works as expected, however `mouseleave` does not seem to be firing. I have the following fiddle set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/shalan/c28cU/8/.

Upon hovering over *ABOUT*, the second level is meant to fade and slide up into view underneath *ABOUT* (which it does), but on `mouseleave` it simply vanishes instead of fading out and sliding down simultaneously.

I am trying to troubleshoot what could be the problem, but I'm running out of ideas. If you look at the Fiddle referenced above, you will see the following lines of CSS (line 38 in CSS pane):

```
/* INITIAL STYLING FOR 2ND LEVEL UL CONTAINER */
nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background:#777;
    top:50px;
}
```

Now if I comment out the line `display:none;`, then `mouseleave` does work as expected, but will obviously activate when you hover in the area below the *ABOUT* list item. I've also tried  different JS methods using `on()`, `hover()`, and `bind()` - the latter which doesn't work.

At this stage, I am unsure if its a JS or CSS issue. I would sincerely appreciate any help in this regard. Many thanks!

Comment: adding `console.log('event: mouseout');` in the hover mouseout function shows that the event is firing, so I'm guessing it's the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey here is a working fiddle for you

http://jsfiddle.net/Gkp34/

I removed the css `display: none;` and instead set the styling `block` with js on hover.

On mouseleave I've set a callback for the animation to set `display: none` when animation is done.

```
function usingOn() {
    nav.on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).find('ul').css('display','block').eq(0).stop(true, true).animate({ opacity:'1' , top: '40px' }, { duration:200, queue:false });
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).find('ul').eq(0).stop(true, true).animate({ opacity:'0' , top: '50px' }, { duration:300, queue:false, complete: function () {
                            // Animation complete.
                            $(this).css('display','none');
                        } });  
        }
    });
}
```

This should work also for your `usingBind()` or `usingHover()` function.

Comment: hyde, u r a star! Thank u! Bit of a *DOH!* moment...didn't think to set the display back to none via JS.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you. The next problem now is coming up. When you move the cursor faster than the animation, you'll see that the callback hides the element again. One suggestion is to put a class like "animating" during the animation to disallow the callback to override an animation.

Comment: or use `hoverIntent()` plugin

Answer (score 0):

use mouseout instead of mouseleave, try that...

Comment: Hi, I've already tried that. Plus `hover()` I believe calls `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`